# Is this the correct syntax for a robots.txt to block Yandex and allow everyone else?

Tags: robots.txt

I'm concerned about the overlap between the `*` rule and the `Yandex` rule.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /
```

Will the first cancel out the second?

Answer (score 4):

You only need:

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /
```

This part is unnecessary:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

because it is implied and used by default (access unless otherwise told).

Comment: Exactly. Except in rare cases, `Allow` is not necessary. Furthermore, some crawlers misinterpret it. Better not to include `Allow` unless absolutely necessary.